# setState of child component to a parentComponent in ReactJs without using render function

Tags: reactjs, sockets

I have a parent component

```
var ViewUser = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
     return {
         ChatMembers: [],
          Messages: []
      };
 }
}
```

and a child component in which im getting my conversation messages using a socket, and changing the state of Messages which is successful

```
  var SideMembers = React.createClass({
     render: function () {
      return (
        <div className="media-body" onClick={this.StartChat} />)
 },
StartChat: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('Get-chat', {
        Conversationid: chatID
    });
    socket.on('Chat-History', function (data) {
        this.setState({ Messages: data });
    }.bind(this));
 }
```

But now I want to set the state of `ViewUser` to the current state of `SideMembers` without using render function

Comment: what do you mean by "without using render function"?

Comment: like by calling a function and sending the props of SideMembers to ViewUser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use props and call a function from the Child function `SideMembers`

```
//Require Child component = SideComponent
var ViewUser = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
 return {
     ChatMembers: [],
      Messages: []
  };
 }
},

updateState:function(date){
this.setState({Messages:data.Messages});
},

render:function(){
  return(
   <SideComponent
      updateState={this.updateState}   
      )
 }
```

Now in the child component call the function sending the data in it

```
var SideMembers = React.createClass({
 render: function () {
  return (
    <div className="media-body" onClick={this.StartChat} />)
 },
     StartChat: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('Get-chat', {
    Conversationid: chatID
         });
     socket.on('Chat-History', function (data) {
       this.setState({ Messages: data });
       var msg = this.state;
       this.props.updateState(msg);
     }.bind(this));
 }
```

Hopefully it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to update parent component - `ViewUser` from child component - `SideMembers`.

In order to accomplish that, you need to pass a function from `ViewUser`

```html
var ViewUser = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      ChatMembers: [],
      Messages: []
    };
  }
  
  updateState: function(newMessages) {
    this.setState(Messages: newMessages);
  }
}
```

(Assuming you want to update `Messages`)

Pass `updateState` to `SideMembers` : `<SideMembers ... updateViewState={this.updateState} />`

Then inside `SideMembers` you can call `this.props.updateViewState` to update `ViewUser` state

---

UPDATE example

```html
var SideMembers = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="media-body" onClick={this.StartChat} />
    )
  },
  
  StartChat: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('Get-chat', {
        Conversationid: chatID
    });
    socket.on('Chat-History', function (data) {
        this.setState({ Messages: data });
        this.props.updateViewState(data);
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

Comment: yes but how to call the function exactly ?  from within a StartChat function

Comment: @YahyaAhmed: answer updated. Please make sure to make some adjustments to fit your logical.